# Sending raw HTML to email hoganjs template via nodejs gives raw HTML output on email client

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, hogan.js

I have an angular front end app that sends a `http` `POST` request with the following raw `HTML` as body :

`<h1>Hello World</h1><ol><li>Yo</li><li>Bro</li></ol>`

My `nodejs` backend is sending it using `sendgrid` and I am using `HoganJs` for templating as well.

But I was receiving this on my email.

[image]

**UPDATE**

`nodejs-sendgrid`

```
sendgrid.send({
    to:       req.body.mail.email || "",
    replyto: "someemail@gmail.com",
    from:     "someemail@gmail.com",
    subject:  req.body.mail.subj,
    html:     template.render(req.body.mail),
}, function(err, json) {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Could you show your Node.js code. Specifically the send function and call. like the Sendgrid Node.js helper library if ur using it

Comment: Well I was just sending the raw string `req.body.mail.body` to the `template.render(req.body.mail);` @Iceman

Comment: The helper has a setHtml. it shud set the proper headers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sendgrid.send({
    to:       req.body.mail.email || "",
    replyto: "someemail@gmail.com",
    from:     "someemail@gmail.com",
    subject:  req.body.mail.subj,
    html:     "<b>Hello World</b>",
}, function(err, json) {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Break it down. Instead of hogan try with an html string like "<b>Hello World</b>" and see what happens

Comment: It worked but it kind of a little ugly since my template is too long.

Comment: Tis a bit "hacky" I guess. Can you update your answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117473/discussion-between-iceman-and-the-green-foxx).

Comment: can you console.log `template.render(req.body.mail)` and see what came. Still not getting why it is nt working